Token CPI without signature from PDA works unexpectedly?
In my app I have 2 programs:
Program A which owns "Beastie" PDAs and calls program B, with the Beastie PDA as a signer.
Program B which creates a token approval from the Beastie to another entity.
My understanding is that the Beastie should be a signer in this call from program B to SPL token, but that signed calls from a PDA can only originate from the owner of the PDA (program A).
However the call works, when called as below. What's going on? Will any downstream program be able to make a call with the Beastie PDA as a signer?
TIA!
let ix = spl_token::instruction::approve(           
    &spl_token::ID,                                 
    beastie_ata.key,                                
    board_ata.key,                                  
    beastie.key,                                    
    &[],              // No signer pubkeys          
    amount,                                         
)?;                                                 
anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
    &ix,                                            
    &[beastie_ata, board_ata, beastie],             
    &[]               // No signer seeds            
).map_err(Into::into)                               


It works because Program A has already granted signer rights to beastie during the transaction, and this signer privilege propagates through the instruction to the SPL Token Program. Other programs cannot reuse this authority unless explicitly allowed by Program A.

Thanks. Ok, so signer status propagates downstream; not bad but a bit of a tricky detail, since I've seen people suggest that you can verify which program is calling by checking for PDA signer status, and chatgpt insists that it does not propagate this way, but rather, only to "explicity" authorised programs!
